# Reactjs it goes back to the home page after pop up window is closed

Tags: reactjs, popup

I am trying to create a popup window in my React application, it is succeeded, but when I closed it, it goes back to the previous page(home page). I want the popup window close, but stay in the same page. Any idea?

My popup.js :

```
function Popup(props) {
  return (props.trigger) ? (
    <div className='popup'>
         <div className="popup-inner">
                <button className='close-btn' onclick={()=> props.setTrigger(false)}>Close</button>
                {props.children}
        </div>
    </div>
  ) : "";
}

export default Popup
```

my React js :

```
<div className="field">
            <div className="control">
                <div className = "analysis-buttons">
                     <button type="button" onClick={()=> setButtonPopup(true)} className="btn-small">
                     Analysis By Category
                    </button>
                    <Popup trigger = {buttonPopup} setTrigger={setButtonPopup}>
                       {analysisResultByCategory}
                    </Popup>

                    <button type="button" onClick={()=> setButtonPopup(true)} className="btn-small">
                     Analysis By Store Name
                    </button>
                    <Popup trigger = {buttonPopup} setTrigger=  {setButtonPopup}>
                       {analysisResultByDesc}
                    </Popup>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: What code controls whether the home page or the [other] page displays?

Comment: Please provide a minimal producible code for us to help you. As of now, we are missing important pieces to understand how you are working with your states.

Comment: I already provide more codes by posting more answers

Comment: It ends up in my Popup.js I should use onClick instead of onclick.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping!My home.js is as follows, and the popup window is at "Money Management"  /add page which is code that I provided in my first section at Reactjs code.

My Home.js is

```
const Home = () => {
    return (
        <section id='home'>
          
            <div className="container home__container">

                <div className="navbar">
                    <a href="#recipes">Recipes</a>
                    <a href="/list">Photos</a>
                    <a href="/add">Money Management</a>
                    <a href="/">Home</a>
                </div>
            </div> 
            </section>

    )
}

export default Home
```

And my App.js code for the route is :

My app.js which controls the routes is :

```
 const App = () => {
      return (
    
      <BrowserRouter>
          <div className="container">
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
              <Route path="list" element={<ListCreditCardStatements/>} />
              <Route path="add" element={<AddCreditCardStmnt />} />
              </Routes>
              </div>
              </BrowserRouter>
              );
    }
    
    export default App
```

Comment: It ends up in my Popup.js I should use onClick instead of onclick.